Is there a name for the belief that Christ in heaven no longer has a human body or nature?
I have encountered a guy online who insists that Christ no longer has human flesh or a human body.  Sometimes he seems to say that Christ no longer has a human nature but I haven't been able to pin him down on that.
This doesn't sound like any of the major heresies I'm familiar with from the first five centuries of the church and I'm wondering if it has a name; I haven't been able to find one for this and would like to research it -- and having a name would help.
For what it's worth, one of his arguments is that the phrase "in the days of His flesh" in Hebrews indicates that Christ no longer has flesh.
edit:
This guy affirms that salvation was achieved on the Cross, and agrees that physical existence is good, but seems to regard Christ's human body as a sort of temporary tool for accomplishing redemption and thus no longer necessary. He also gives the impression that having a human body in heaven would be degrading.

Sounds like Gnosticism to me. One tenet of it is that salvation comes only by having the "right" knowledge. The other main tenet is that the physical body and flesh is evil and sinful, and only the "spiritual" form of anything can be good.

Neither of those matches.  This guy affirms that salvation was achieved on the Cross, and agrees that physical existence is good, but seems to regard Christ's human body as a sort of temporary tool for accomplishing redemption and thus is no longer necessary.  He also gives the impression that having a human body in heaven would be degrading. / I think I'm going to copy part of this to the post itself.

A few questions that might help narrow down the answer: 1) Does this guy identify as part of a tradition or denomination? 2) Does he deny that the post-resurrection appearances were Christ in his physical body (i.e., does he deny a physical resurrection), or does he claim that the shedding of the body occurred sometime later, such as at the ascension? 3) Does he claim that Christ no longer has a human nature in any sense, or is it just the body that's no more?

2 Peter 1:13–14 says "Yea, I think it meet, as long as I am in this tabernacle, to stir you up by putting you in remembrance;
Knowing that shortly I must put off this my tabernacle, even as our Lord Jesus Christ hath shewed me.".
The physical human body (including Jesus's) is only a temporary dwelling (some translations use the word "tent"), similar in form but not substance to the immortal spiritual body that the saved (including Jesus) are reborn into.
How is that heresy?

This is a quarrel over definition of human body. After resurrection we become like angels. It is not an ordinary human body.

@Michael16 No, it's an argument over whether Jesus even has a human body regardless of whether it is "ordinary" or transformed somehow.  His view is that having a body is degrading to the Word.

Have you still not been able to determine the denomination that "this guy" represents?

The Christian creed ends with "the resurrection of the body and the life everlasting" - not with the hope of a disembodied heavenly existence after death. Here is one expression of why this is significant for those who claim to believe the Bible:

"Jesus died and was raised to life in glory. As the prototype of the
new creation, Jesus ate and drank with his disciples after his
resurrection. "Touch me, and see," he invited. "For a spirit does not
have flesh and bones as you see that I have" (Lk 24:39). Not only is
the bodily resurrection of Christ affirmed in the Gospels, where Jesus
eats with his disciples and even invites Thomas to inspect his wounds;
it is clearly taught in the letters of Paul, particularly 1
Corinthians 15. ...Just as we have borne the image of the man of dust
[Adam], we shall also bear the image of the man of heaven" (vv.
48-49)." Pilgrim Theology, Michael Horton, pp.444-446, Zondervan,
2011

Now, I am familiar with one group that clearly denies that, and they are not alone. This is where identifying a denomination would be more helpful than finding a theological label on a particular teaching.
The group I know of denies that Jesus was resurrected with a body, saying that God caused his corpse to disappear and brought a spirit creature out of the tomb. This spirit materialised into visible human bodies before returning to heaven, they say, only giving an illusion of a glorified body. Although they agree that many disciples saw him ascend bodily up into the clouds, they say that it was only an appearance of a body, which resumed its resurrected spirit form from then, till eternity.
They claim that all humans who are to go to heaven must give up human nature to obtain divine nature in order to share with Christ in his heavenly glory. They "must give up human life forever", as did Jesus. In their own rendition of the Bible, they give certain Greek words about the heavenly resurrection English words that subtly support their doctrine. Now, that does involve denying the Christian teaching that nobody can do anything to earn, or merit, or contribute towards their salvation (as they are offering to God their human nature and human body in exchange for glorification.) It also brings in the theological doctrine of Theosis (deification), but only slightly, and your discussions will go off-topic with your contact if you raise it. It is likely that your contact also believes in soul annihilation at death (for those who don't go instantly to heaven, that is. All others, they say, will cease to exist except in God's memory, till the resurrection at the start of an earthly millennium.) It may also be that your contact believes in Christ having had a starting point in time, and is not, and never has been fully God.
It may be more helpful for identification purposes, to ask your contact about such related beliefs, and then you might be able to ask a question such as, "Are you part of the Worldwide Church of God, or Jehovah's Witnesses?" (There are other groups with variations on this rejection of Christ having been resurrected with his body glorified, denying that he is still called "the man from heaven" in the New Testament.) This is just an example of how to get to the root of the matter that perplexes you. Ask outright what denominational group he identifies with. If he is unwilling to answer plainly, then he needs to be asked why he is being so coy.
It's not a theological tag you need to be able to use as a label, but to know if he supports an already-identified group that is outside mainstream (i.e. orthodox) Christianity, for that particular belief your contact is promoting could be dependent on other heretical beliefs.

A good point, that it is better to locate a heresy in regard to the people who hold it than to give it a label. 'The doctrine of the Nicolaitans which thing I hate' says the Son of man in vision to John. Up-voted +1.

All I could get from him is "non-denominational Bible-believing Christian".

@Traildude  You speak of the "guy online". There are many who do not identify with any denomination but are keen Bible-studying believers in Christ Jesus. I know that his view is shared by some named denominations, like Worldwide Church of God, Jehovah's Witnesses etc but he doesn't belong to a denomination. Some Brethern folk can describe themselves as "non-denominational Bible-believing Christians" but they do not hold to that view this person has. Or maybe he did belong to a group but has been put out or left.

You are looking for a specific type of "Christological Heresy" specifically one of the ones that denies Christ's Humanity.

The denial of  Christ's humanity -- which gave rise to Docetism, Marcionism, Gnosticism, Apollinarianism, Monarchianism, Patripassianism, Sabellianism, Adoptionism, Dynamic Monarchianism.

Basically Jesus was a human and then became Divine = Adoptionism or Dynamic Monarchianism.
It has been around for quite awhile. The "Flesh would be degrading in heaven" statement sounds like the gnostic "material is evil" type of sentiment, but you say the general claim is that physical world is good. The idea that "human flesh would be degrading" is absolutely laughable considering that God indwells all of creation. (Panentheism)

As Ray pointed out in the comment below, it could be a type of "Modalism"
This would be something like God was Divine, Became Human, and than was Divine again.

It looks like whomever you are talking about is "mixing and matching" some.
If you wanna chat about it and discuss arguments that should defeat such a heresy you can always make a chat with me, and others will likely join in as well.

"specifically one of the ones that denies Christ's Humanity" — I suspect not. It sounds like a denomination that believes Jesus was fully God, became fully human, and then became fully God again, in a purely spirit form. As a divine spirit, Christ can materialize as a physical being, just as can angels and just as will his siblings when they are resurrected as immortal spirit beings. The concept of a physical body in Heaven, God's spiritual realm, is what sounds like heresy with respect to what the Bible teaches.

@RayButterworth Your first sentence there seems a good summary, except all I could get from him is "non-denominational Bible-believing Christian".

@Traildude Then he falls into the realm of "personal interpretation" which is generally not recommended (by my particular church) due to how easy it is to interpret something wrong. As you can see from my answer, I believe Christ still has a Human body, Human Nature, etc.
